# ValueError: too many values to unpack 3

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
  1 i#:coding:utf-8
  2 #0导入模块，生成模拟数据集
  3 import tensorflow as tf
  4 import numpy as np
  5 BATCH_SIZE = 8
  6 seed = 23455
  7 
  8 #给予seed产生随机数
  9 rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)
 10 #随机数返回32行2列矩阵 表示32组 体积和重量 作为输入数据集
 11 X = rng.rand(32,3)
 12 
 13 Y = [[int(x0+x1<1)] for (x0,x1) in X]
 14 print "X:\n",X
 15 print "Y:\n",Y
 16 
 17 #1定义神经网络的输入，参数和输出，定义向前传播过程
 18 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
 19 y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
 20 
 21 w1= tf.variable(tf.random([2,3], stddev=1, seed=1))
 22 w2= tf.variable(tf.random([3,1], stddev=1, seed=1))
 23 
 24 a =tf.matmul(x,w1)
 25 y =tf.matmul(a,w2)
 26 
 27 #定义损失函数集反向传播方法
 28 loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y-y_))
 29 #train_step = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.001,0.9).minimize(loss)
 30 #train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)
 31 
 32 #3生成会话，训练steps轮
 33 with tf.Session() as sess:
 34     init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
 35     sess.run(init_op)
 36     # 输出目前未经训练的参数取值。
 37     print "w1:\n", sess.run(w1)
 38     print "w2:\n", sess.run(w2)
 39     print "\n"
 40 
 41     #train the model
 42     STEPS=3000
 43     for i in range(STEPS):
 44         start =(i*BATCH_SIZE) % 32
 45         end = start + BATCH_SIZE
 46         sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: X[start:end], y_: Y[start:end]})
 47         if i % 500 == 0:
 48             total_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: X, y_: Y})
 49             print("After %d training steps(s), loss on all data in %g" % (i,     total_loss))
 50 
 51     #output the trained value of variables
 52     print "\n"
 53     print "w1:\n", sess.run(w1)
 54     print "w2:\n", sess.run(w2)
```

File "tf3_6.py", line 13, in 
    Y = [[int(x0+x1<1)] for (x0,x1) in X]
ValueError: too many values to unpack.

The code i don't think it is wrong but i still noticed the value error so i hope you guys to help me cope this question thanks a lot

Comment: what is the value of `X`?

Comment: 9 rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)
 10 #随机数返回32行2列矩阵 表示32组 体积和重量 作为输入数据集
 11 X = rng.rand(32,3)
 12 
 13 Y = [[int(x0+x1<1)] for (x0,x1) in X]
 14 print "X:\n",X
 15 print "Y:\n",Y

Comment: It's best to edit your question instead of add code in the comments. Try to add as much details as is required for someone to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i will and i have already re-edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of `X` is `(32, 3)`, but in your list comprehension, you are only trying to unpack 2 values:

```
Y = [[int(x0+x1<1)] for (x0,x1) in X]
```

Either change the shape of your array of rands:

```
X = rng.rand(32,2)
```

Or throw away the third rand in your list comp:

```
Y = [[int(x0+x1<1)] for (x0,x1, _) in X]
```

Comment: That's great, glad I could help! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.